# Integer vs. Regular Division

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, collatz

Using // and / in the following code (location marked in-code), I get different answers:

```
x = 2**(221) + 1

count = 0

while x != 1:
    if x%2 == 0: 
        x = x//2 # HERE: In this line - case (1) x = x//2, case(2) x = x/2
        count += 1
    elif x%2 == 1:
        x = 3*x + 1
        count += 1
        
count
```

In case (1), count = 1754. In case (2), count = 229. Why are the outputs different??

Comment: Floating point numbers of that size have no accuracy anymore.

Comment: Regular division always produces a float, even if the result could be an integer.

Comment: Also note that `2**(221) + 1` will be represented exact using Python's integers (they are unbounded), while floating point values will be restricted to 64 bit approximations. In Python3, a division with a single `/` will always result in a floating point value.